# PDF content displays in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, download

The requirement is the pdf file should be opened when the pdf link is selected on the xhtml page. The pdf opens properly for chrome and firefox but displays empty content for Internet explorer.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=sample.pdf");
```

Comment: Is the PDF been downloaded over HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, it is been downloaded over HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Yes, it is been downloaded over HTTPS.*

This is a MSIE specific quirk. You need to add the following headers to the response.

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
```

See also Microsoft Knowledge Base [Q316431](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431).